# Check enddate for intermediate certificate in chain

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509

I recently had a problem where a server certificate was not set to expire, but the intermediate cert in its chain had expired, thus preventing my WebLogic server from starting.  I am familiar with using `openssl s_client -connect server:443 -showcerts | openssl x509 -enddate` to get the server cert expiration date, but is it possible to do the same for the other certs in the chain?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl s_client -connect server:443 -showcerts` returns all certificates in chain except for root (which is correct). Just parse these certificates out of the output and run `openssl x509 -enddate` on each of them.

Comment: By 'parse these certificates', I think pepo means split the output of `openssl s_client` into separate files, delimiting on the lines that say `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. Each of these individual cert files can be fed as input to `openssl x509`.